# Order By Aggregrate Function MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have come up with another question.I am trying to devise a MySql query.

I have a `Users` table and a `Ratings` table with `user_id` as a foreign key in ratings table.

Now I have to get the user who has maximum average ratings

So I did:

```
SELECT blah blah FROM Users USR
INNER JOIN Ratings RTN on USR.id = RTN.user_id
order by avg(RTN.rating)
```

But i feel this is wrong and its also not working either.Is there a way to get users ordered by average ratings they received in a descending order?

Regards
Himanshu Sharma.

Comment: Yep, you need to actually do an aggregation.  MySQL lets you use aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY` which is pretty useless.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @JNK What if we do select avg where userid = some value.That case doesnt need a group by

Comment: Yes, but if you have any unaggregated fields only MySQL will let you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't seem very wrong actually (as a start), I would write it like this:

```
SELECT USR.id, AVG(RTN.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM Users USR
INNER JOIN Ratings RTN ON USR.id = RTN.user_id
GROUP BY USR.id
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inline view that calculates the Average rating and then join to it if you want to include the rating data.

```
SELECT blah blah 
FROM Users USR
   INNER JOIN Ratings RTN 
   ON USR.id = RTN.user_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT avg(RTN.rating) Avg_rating 
              FROM Ratings RTN
              GROUP BY 
                rtn.user_id) a_rtn
  ON  USR.id = A_RTN.user_id

ORDER BY avg(A_RTN.AVg_rating) DESC
```

If you want just the user data than you just need a standard Group By

```
SELECT USR.First_name, USR.Last_name, etc
FROM Users USR
   INNER JOIN Ratings RTN 
   ON USR.id = RTN.user_id

GROUP BY 
   USR.First_name, USR.Last_name, etc    
ORDER BY avg(A_RTN.AVg_rating) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    select blah, blah
    from users usr
    join (
    select rtn.user_id, avg(rtn.rating) as avg_rating
    from users usr
    join ratings rtn on usr.id = rtn.user_id
    group by rtn.user_id
    ) t on t.user_id = usr.id 
    order by avg_rating desc
```